# How to use the user ID in the "more" link of a views block?

Tags: views, users, blocks, 10

I created a media field for users. Users can therefore add media to their profile.

I want to display their media on their user page.

I created a media view block with a relationship "Connects each User with a field_media defined for the media element" and a contextual filter "User: User ID" as in the previous relationship and with "When the value filter is NOT available" > "Provide default value" > "User ID from route context".

I added to my view a page with the same parameters and the path "user/%user/profile-media". On the block, in pagination, I configured it like:

- “More” link: Yes
- Link display: Page

My problem is that when I add the block to the user's page, hovering over the "more" link, displays the "user/all/profile-media" uri.

Why can't I get the user ID in the uri ?

In the case below, the user id is 34. The uri should be "user/34/profile-media"

[image]

Here is a view that you can import, it is very simple :

```
uuid: 58bfdf24-2d81-4c77-8908-7d5975496191
langcode: fr
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - user
id: test
label: test
module: views
description: ''
tag: ''
base_table: users_field_data
base_field: uid
display:
  default:
    id: default
    display_title: Default
    display_plugin: default
    position: 0
    display_options:
      title: test
      fields:
        name:
          id: name
          table: users_field_data
          field: name
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          entity_type: user
          entity_field: name
          plugin_id: field
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            make_link: false
            absolute: false
            word_boundary: false
            ellipsis: false
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: true
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: user_name
          settings: {  }
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
      pager:
        type: some
        options:
          offset: 0
          items_per_page: 5
      exposed_form:
        type: basic
        options:
          submit_button: Apply
          reset_button: false
          reset_button_label: Reset
          exposed_sorts_label: 'Sort by'
          expose_sort_order: true
          sort_asc_label: Asc
          sort_desc_label: Desc
      access:
        type: none
        options: {  }
      cache:
        type: none
        options: {  }
      empty: {  }
      sorts: {  }
      arguments:
        uid:
          id: uid
          table: users_field_data
          field: uid
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          entity_type: user
          entity_field: uid
          plugin_id: user_uid
          default_action: default
          exception:
            value: all
            title_enable: false
            title: All
          title_enable: false
          title: ''
          default_argument_type: user
          default_argument_options:
            user: false
          summary_options:
            base_path: ''
            count: true
            override: false
            items_per_page: 25
          summary:
            sort_order: asc
            number_of_records: 0
            format: default_summary
          specify_validation: false
          validate:
            type: none
            fail: 'not found'
          validate_options: {  }
          break_phrase: false
          not: false
      filters:
        status:
          id: status
          table: users_field_data
          field: status
          entity_type: user
          entity_field: status
          plugin_id: boolean
          value: '1'
          group: 1
          expose:
            operator: ''
      style:
        type: default
      row:
        type: fields
      query:
        type: views_query
        options:
          query_comment: ''
          disable_sql_rewrite: false
          distinct: false
          replica: false
          query_tags: {  }
      relationships: {  }
      use_more: true
      use_more_always: true
      use_more_text: more
      link_display: page_1
      link_url: ''
      header: {  }
      footer: {  }
      display_extenders: {  }
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - url
      tags: {  }
  block_1:
    id: block_1
    display_title: Block
    display_plugin: block
    position: 1
    display_options:
      display_extenders: {  }
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - url
      tags: {  }
  page_1:
    id: page_1
    display_title: Page
    display_plugin: page
    position: 2
    display_options:
      fields:
        name:
          id: name
          table: users_field_data
          field: name
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          entity_type: user
          entity_field: name
          plugin_id: field
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            make_link: false
            absolute: false
            word_boundary: false
            ellipsis: false
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: true
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: user_name
          settings: {  }
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
        created:
          id: created
          table: users_field_data
          field: created
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          entity_type: user
          entity_field: created
          plugin_id: field
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: false
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: timestamp
          settings:
            date_format: medium
            custom_date_format: ''
            timezone: ''
            tooltip:
              date_format: long
              custom_date_format: ''
            time_diff:
              enabled: false
              future_format: '@interval hence'
              past_format: '@interval ago'
              granularity: 2
              refresh: 60
              description: ''
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
        changed:
          id: changed
          table: users_field_data
          field: changed
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          entity_type: user
          entity_field: changed
          plugin_id: field
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: false
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: timestamp
          settings:
            date_format: medium
            custom_date_format: ''
            timezone: ''
            tooltip:
              date_format: long
              custom_date_format: ''
            time_diff:
              enabled: false
              future_format: '@interval hence'
              past_format: '@interval ago'
              granularity: 2
              refresh: 60
              description: ''
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
        access:
          id: access
          table: users_field_data
          field: access
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          entity_type: user
          entity_field: access
          plugin_id: field
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: false
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: timestamp
          settings:
            date_format: medium
            custom_date_format: ''
            timezone: ''
            tooltip:
              date_format: long
              custom_date_format: ''
            time_diff:
              enabled: false
              future_format: '@interval hence'
              past_format: '@interval ago'
              granularity: 2
              refresh: 60
              description: ''
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
      defaults:
        fields: false
      display_extenders: {  }
      path: user/%user/test
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - url
      tags: {  }
```

Comment: Welcome :) Have you configured the Context filter ID option on Block settings? Check if More link requires turning on Ajax in Views.

Comment: @prkos Thank you, yes I did your configuration correctly. Here are screenshots of my view https://ibb.co/TP4wc3G , https://ibb.co/RCFbYzV , https://ibb.co/Cn4Pr5g , https://ibb.co/XWmkGq2 It seems correct and logical, I don't understand why it doesn't work

Comment: Why did you include node views page screenshots? Your Contextual filter isn't showing the settings you noted in your questions, user from context/from URL are not the same. You should also add the info to your question.

Comment: If you use user ID from context you will get the visitors ID, not the ID of the user who's page is being visited. So you do need to use the default ID from URL, but you're using the wrong Contextual, it should be User ID, not Content ID.

Comment: @prkos I just updated my question. I tested on simplytest.me and it seems to be a Drupal Core bug. Can you confirm ? THANKS

Comment: You can import my view to test, by adding the "test" block on the user's page. The lein "more" does not display the user ID in its uri, but "all"

Comment: View config isn't enough to import, there are changes on the Media and users as well.